# Is their any cordova plugin which provides background service for getting device location even if android/ios app is killed

Tags: android, ios, cordova, sencha-touch, cordova-plugins

I used https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation plugin which provides device location when application is running or in background but it doesn't work if application is killed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use options *'stopOnTerminate'* and *'startOnBoot'* of this plugin and your app should survive the kill, you can continue getting the location updates.

Comment: First of all thanks for reply. I have checked  'stopOnTerminate' and 'startOnBoot' on android. But still not getting device location after app get killed. Is there anything i missed other than this?

Comment: are you using the Callback function to post data to your server or anywhere ?

Comment: Yes, I am using callback function.

Comment: use _'url'_ option posting data to your service.. when the APP is killed your activity might also be killed, so does the callback.. but service might survive the kill.. so you should be using _'url'_ option of the plugin rather than the callbk, callbk wont be called after the app is killed

Comment: Thank you very much. I have used 'url' option and it worked. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Hey @Hus, this plugin is perfectly working on android but on ios, I am not getting location. Is there anything i have to add in plist file ?

Comment: i didnt use it with iOS, but it should work the same way, if you are using _url_ option .. add callbk function to your code in iOS, check if you are getting anything in callBack function

Comment: I am getting location only when app is in foreground for ios.

Comment: check if iOS is blocking your application in background.. check anything which is equivalent to doze mode of android in iOS, like standby time settings etc.. also try setting _saveBatteryOnBackground: false_

Comment: @Hus If user close app and have internet connection does tracking will still continue for IOS and Android with this plugin If I use url option ?

Comment: As far as I remember, Yes it worked for android.. don't know for ios, I never tested it with ios

Comment: Hi Guys, I am still facing this issue. when i kill the app background services is not working in Ionic Cordova app. Please help me with code.  Thanks